# Добавление видео с YouTube

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, mobile-development

Как настроить webview, чтобы отобразить проигрыватель ютюба строго по размерам вьюшки? Надо убрать белый кантик, проигрыватель приходится свайпом пальца выравнивать по центру вьюшки, надо чтоб не скролилось

```
let youtubeURL = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Rg6GLVUnnpM"
myVideoView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(videoView.frame.width)\" height=\"\(videoView.frame.height)\" src=\"\(youtubeURL)?&playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)
```

сама вьюшка сейчас 310*210, размеры ее тож менял, и делал ее на всю ширину экрана, но тогда видео на ютюбе отображается гигантских размеров
При проигрывании ролика на весь экран в приложении запущенного в симуляторе выдает:

Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) ...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и тд, не пойму что с ограничениями не так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myVideoView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
myVideoView.loadHTMLString("<html><body style='margin:0'><iframe width=\(myVideoView.frame.width) height=\(myVideoView.frame.height) src='\(youtubeURL)?&playsinline=1' frameborder=0 allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>", baseURL: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

На англоязычном SO есть [вот такое решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15486482/1558147)
Если адаптировать по swift, то

```
let youtubeURL = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Rg6GLVUnnpM"
myVideoView.loadHTMLString("<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"100%%\" height=\"100%%\" src=\"\(youtubeURL)?&playsinline=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)
```

Comment: нет не работает, картинка в плеере плывет

Comment: нашел такое решение, но скрол не убрался, все равно картинка ездит если палцем потянуть проигрыватель ютюба

Comment: myVideoView.loadHTMLString("<html><body style='margin:0'><iframe width=\(videoView.frame.width) height=\(videoView.frame.height) src='\(youtubeURL)?&playsinline=1' frameborder=0 allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>", baseURL: nil)